# How can you draw to a Canvas element or to the web browser when using dotnetcore and blazor server project

Tags: javascript, c#, html5-canvas, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server project in Visual Studio 2019.  In javascript you can draw to an HTML Canvas element.  I was wondering how I could do this from blazor server project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NuGet Package for Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 is called:
Blazor.Extensions.Canvas